# Xamarin - Bundle Invalid Error When Uploading to App Store

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, macos, xamarin

I've been having this problem for a few days, and can't find any solution.

I made my app with Xamarin Studio. I am trying to upload an update for my it to iTunes Connect through Xcode. But when trying to validate the app I get the following error: 
`"This bundle is invalid. New apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with public."`
 Dissecting this error it makes it sound like it thinks I'm using a beta SDK, which I'm not (full system specs below). Even weirder is that if I go through Xamarin Studio's Archive validation it tells me everything is fine. But when I go through Application Loader it tells me the following: 
`"ERROR ITMS-9000: This bundle is invalid. New apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with public (GM) versions of Xcode 5.1.1 or higher and iOS 7 SDK. Do not submit apps built with beta software."` 
Obviously this is the same error as before, just a little more detailed. But the system specs it outlines, are exactly the same as I am using.

Hopefully someone out there can lend me a hand! :D

System Specs:

- Mac OSX 10.9.3
- Xcode 5.1.1 (Downloaded from the Mac App Store)
- iOS 7 SDK, building for iOS 7.1
- Xamarin Studio 5.0
- Application Loader 2.9.1

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your project in Xamarin Studio, then double click on Info.plist. Click on `Use Asset Catalogs` for both sections: Universal Icons & Universal Launch Images. It should create two new folders:

1. Resources/Images.xassets/AppIcons.appiconset
2. Resources/Images.xassets/LanuchImage.lanuchimage

Go to AppIcons.appiconset folder and make sure that you have the following file names:

- AppIcon57x57.png
- AppIcon57x57@2x.png
- AppIcon72x72@2x~.png
- AppIcon72x72~ipad.png

Rename your icons if you don't have them and double click on `Content.json` to assign them.

Comment: This is very, very, very, very late. But I am working on a new project from when I posted this and got the same error. This solved it! Thanks so much!